# Rails: Devise: Undefined Method `username' cannot access attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to return an attribute of my user model in a view generated by my jobs controller

```
@accepteduser = User.find_by_id(@job.accepted).username || "no one...yet."
```

Let me simplify this so you can see the problem:

```
User.find_by_id(1).username
```

If I run that in my Rails console it returns "ASDF" if I run that on my Jobs show veiw or Jobs controller it gives me this error: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass when I try to access the page.

Extra Info:
I'm new to rails so I did some other testing. I switched it to be a different model I'm opening and it worked just fine:

```
Jobs.find_by_id(1).title
```

That returned "Test Job" So the only difference between the User model and the Jobs model is that the User model is created by Devise gem (I think) but it still `< ActiveRecord::Base` So what is going on? do I need to do something special to call user because I'm using devise?

Keep in mind I can call current_user.username and it works great. but I don't want the current user in this case I want the user of a specific ID. so how do I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_by_id` method is querying your database based on the receiver class. So, assuming standard naming, `Job.find_by_id` is looking in the `jobs` table and `User.find_by_id` is looking in the `users` table. Similarly, the former returns an instance of `Job` and the latter returns an instance of `User`.

If `User.find_by_id(1)` returns non-nil in the Rails console, then it should also return non-nil in a view *unless* the databases in question are different (e.g. development database vs. test database).

Comment: I know it should, thats what has be so confused. its all development env.

Comment: Have tried literally writing out `User.find_by_id(1)` from your view and seeing `nil`?

Comment: So there is definitely a User with an id of 1 in your dev database?

Comment: indeed, peter and alex. now, by testing I've noticed that in my console if I try `User.find_by_id(2).username` it gives me the `NoMethod username` error. there is no 2nd user. so it gives the error if it returns nil so the question is how do I get it to avoid running the .username if it returns nil?

Comment: Oh! I figured something else out! The reason I was getting the error every time was because I had unfixed code in the view that was triggering the error when my jobs controller code was correct! I had `User.find_by_id(@job.accepted).username` when `job.accepted` was nil in the view at the same time my controller said `User.find_by_id(1).username` which was actually working correctly. Sorry about that guys!!! but I would like to insert some code so that it doesn't give that error if `job.accepted` is unassigned.

Comment: Here's the code I ended up with so that it wouldn't throw that error when the variable was nil. `Accepted By: <%= @job.accepted? ? User.find_by_id(@job.accepted).username : "no one... yet" %>`

Comment: Thanks for the accepte and the follow-up. I'm glad I left my untested/erroneous code suggestion as only a comment (which I just deleted ;-)).